# How to get `dtlb_load_misses.miss_causes_a_walk` performance counter on a virtual machine?

Tags: linux, performancecounter, tlb

I'm trying to get some TLB performance counters in a virtual machine (ESXi machine) using `perf` command but it always returns zero. I noted that the `virtualize performance counters` is disabled on the VM, resulting in `perf` always returns zero.

Since the provider is not able to enable the `virtualize performance counters`, how can I get the *`dtlb_load_misses.miss_causes_a_walk`* on this VM?